# How to host and play videos in a drupal site?

Tags: files

Just that, I need to host and play videos in a drupal site. I mean not using vimeo, youtube...

Comment: You probably want to host videos on amazon (S3). Theres a module for youtube http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube but not sure about vimeo.

Comment: I mean to host the videos file in my own hosting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something along the lines of the [Video](http://drupal.org/project/video) module?

> Video module allows you to upload video in any format, play video in
>   any format, transcode video to H.246, Theora, VP8 using Zencoder or
>   FFMPEG automatically creates video thumbnails, stream videos from
>   cloud, HTML5 videos with mobile device playback compatibility. Very
>   reliable API for converting videos and auto thumbnail, embed video to
>   node body using WYSIWYG module (D7 only) and many more.

Answer (score 6):

Another viable option is the [MediaElement.js module](http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement). I've had great success with it, and it's HTML5 too! If your site is on Drupal 7 of course. This module also does sound files as well.

Comment: WHat is its benefit? Does it mean I do not need a video transcoder? I am looking for self hosted video transcoding option. There is ffmpeg, but not all hostings support it.

Answer (score 2):

You can host and play video using [Kaltura](https://drupal.org/project/kaltura#downloads) module

> Kaltura is the world's leading Open-Source Video Platform, providing
>   video management, publishing, authoring, distribution and monetization
>   solutions for media companies, enterprises, educational institutions
>   and service providers. Our customers include HBO, ABC, Disney, Best
>   Buy, Texas Instruments, NYU, MIT, Cornell, and many others.

- Drupal 7 compliant (Kaltura also offers a module for Drupal 6)
- Easy upload of video, audio and image, with automatic transcoding
- Import video directly to your site or record from a webcam
- User Engagement - allow users to add video and audio comments on any page
- Reach your users anywhere and on any device (including iPhone and iPad, web, and set-top boxes
- Full control of the player and content – play your own ads and create your own related content
- Hosting, streaming and automatic transcoding of media - all seamlessly performed on the Kaltura cloud (or on your local Kaltura installation)
- Easy skinning, theming and integration with other Drupal modules
- Flexibility and granularity - Each media file is created as a Drupal Video Field
- Drupal permissions integration – Administrators decide who can view/edit content and metadata, with granular permissions at field level
- Full integration with Drupal Views - including predefined views
- Full synchronization of content, metadata and tags between Drupal and the Kaltura system

Comment: But it is not straight forward to install it. I saw it, but did not understand how to install the community edition.